# css problem stretching middle div holy grail

Tags: html, css, layout

I cannot seem to figure out why my middle div(`menu-item-middle` class) inside the `menuitem` class won't stretch accross. I've spent quite a bit of time on this now and I thought I better post this one because I cannot figure this out. This is what my code looks like.

```
.menu-item  div
{
    display:inline-block
}
.menu-item-left
{
    left:0px; float:left; border:1px solid #000000
}
.menu-item-middle
{
    padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:6px; padding-right:5px; left:39px; float:left; border:1px solid #000000
}
.menu-item-right
{
    width:26px; height:44px; right:0px; clear:right; background-image:url('images/Menu_Item_Arrow.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; border:1px solid #000000
}
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="menu-item">
                <div class="menu-item-left">
                    <div class="item-corner">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-icon">
                        <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-middle">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:5px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">
                                <span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Technology</span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Computers &amp; 
                                Office Supplies</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-right">
                    <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item">
                <div class="menu-item-left">
                    <div class="item-corner">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-icon">
                        <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-middle">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:5px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">
                                <span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">Intersts</span>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Movies Books &amp; 
                                Music</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-right">
                    <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-item">
                <div class="menu-item-left">
                    <div class="item-corner">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-icon">
                        <img alt="" height="36" src="images/spacer.gif" width="36" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-middle">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:5px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#0b83bb">
                                <span style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:.95em; font-weight:bold">
                                Entertainment</span> </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:.7em; color:#0b83bb">Software &amp; 
                                Digital Games</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-right">
                    <img alt="" height="44" src="images/spacer.gif" width="26" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How is this suppose to look, can you show us a screenshot of how you'd like it to render? p.s. Mixing tables and divs is never a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have set the `float` property. If you want to keep it then try adding a `width: 100%` to the class.

Comment: i removed the floats chnaged the width to 100% that doesn't work

Comment: Then the problem should be in the width of the TD holding that div. Try adding width property to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it happen because, the content of this `div` is not same as other two. You can try with

**CSS**

```
.menu-item-middle {min-width:150px}
```

It works from IE8&+